# jQuery add class to specific ID based on MYSQL fetch

Tags: php, html, jquery

I try to solve this problem:

1. I have a from MYSQL fetched element in PHP:

```
<button class="like-btn" id="idLike-'.$row['id'].'">Button text</button>
```

Currently, there are 3 fetched elements and every fetched element has its own id automatically e.g. idLike-1, idLike-2, idLike-3 etc.

2. I added a Jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#idLike-2").click(function(){
        $("#idLike-2").addClass("btn-first");
    });
});
```

This works fine with the idLike-2 element of course, but I cannot find an ultimate solution for this script to work every id separately e.g. if I click on the idLike-1, only this element has a new class.

Thank you for your help!

**Update:**

If I try to save the current state of the element into the localStorage, the state of all elements will be saved. My full code:

````
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).ready(function() {
  if(localStorage.getItem('isCliked')){
      $(".like-btn").addClass('liked-btn');

      $(".like-btn").removeClass('like-btn');
  }
  $('.like-btn').on('click',function() {
    $(this).addClass('liked-btn');

    $(this).removeClass('like-btn');
    // set the value upon clicking
    localStorage.setItem('isCliked', true)
  });
});```
````

Answer (score 2):

You could solve that by using a more general "class" selector like so:

PHP fetched HTML:

```
<button class="like-btn">Button text</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".like-btn").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("btn-first");
    });
});
```

You can target the jQuery element triggering the event using the `$(this)` selector.

References:

- https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/
- https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-element

Comment: It works, however, if I want to save the state of the clicked element into the localStorage, the state of all items will be changed e.g. every button will be red. Check my update.

Answer (score 0):

1 alternative option is using wildcard on id.

```js
$('button[id*="idLike-"]').click(function() {
  $('button').removeClass("btn-first");
  $(this).addClass("btn-first");
});
```

```css
.btn-first {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="like-btn" id="idLike-1">Button text</button>
<button class="like-btn" id="idLike-2">Button text</button>
<button class="like-btn" id="idLike-3">Button text</button>
```